# Best way to write Fastest Euclidean distance in Scala

Tags: scala, optimization

I would like to find the fastest way to write euclidean distance in Scala. After some attemps, i'm here.

```
def euclidean[V <: Seq[Double]](dot1: V, dot2: V): Double = {
    var d = 0D
    var i = 0
    while( i < dot1.size ) {
        val toPow2 = dot1(i) - dot2(i)
        d += toPow2 * toPow2
        i += 1
    }
    sqrt(d)
}
```

Fastest results are obtain with `mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double]` as `V` and no `collection.parallel._` are authorized for various vector size from 2 up to 10000

For those who desire to test [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) its slower with following distance function :

```
def euclideanDV(v1: DenseVector[Double], v2: DenseVector[Double]) = norm(v1 - v2)
```

If anyone knows any pure scala code or library that could help to improve speed it would be greatly appreciated.

The way i tested speed was i follow.

```
val te1 = 0L
val te2 = 0L
val runNumber = 100000
val warmUp = 60000
(0 until runNumber).foreach{ x =>
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  euclidean1(v1, v2)
  val t2 = System.nanoTime
  euclidean2(v1, v2)
  val t3 = System.nanoTime
  if( x >= warmUp ) {
    te1 += t2 - t1
    te2 += t3 - t2
  }
}
```

Here a some of my tries

```
// Fast on ArrayBuffer, quadratic on List
def euclidean1[V <: Seq[Double]](v1: V, v2: V) = 
{
  var d = 0D
  var i = 0
  while( i < v1.size ){
    val toPow2 = v1(i) - v2(i)
    d += toPow2 * toPow2
    i += 1
  }
  sqrt(d)
}    

// Breeze test
def euclideanDV(v1: DenseVector[Double], v2: DenseVector[Double]) = norm(v1 - v2)    

// Slower than euclidean1
def euclidean2[V <: Seq[Double]](v1: V, v2: V) = 
{
  var d = 0D
  var i = 0
  while( i < v1.size )
  {
    d += pow(v1(i) - v2(i), 2)
    i += 1
  }
  d
}    

// Slower than 1 for Vsize ~< 1000 and a bit better over 1000 on ArrayBuffer
def euclidean3[V <: Seq[Double]](v1: V, v2: V) = 
{
  var d = 0D
  var i = 0
  (0 until v1.size).foreach{ i=>
    val toPow2 = v1(i) - v2(i)
    d += toPow2 * toPow2
  }
  sqrt(d)
}    

// Slower than 1 for Vsize ~< 1000 and a bit better over 1000 on ArrayBuffer
def euclidean3bis(dot1: Seq[Double], dot2: Seq[Double]): Double =
{
  var sum = 0D
  dot1.indices.foreach{ id =>
    val toPow2 = dot1(id) - dot2(id)
    sum += toPow2 * toPow2
  }
  sqrt(sum)
}    

// Slower than 1
def euclidean4[V <: Seq[Double]](v1: V, v2: V) = 
{
  var d = 0D
  var i = 0
  val vz = v1.zip(v2)
  while( i < vz.size )
  {
    val (a, b) = vz(i)
    val toPow2 = a - b
    d += toPow2 * toPow2
    i += 1
  }
  d
}    

// Slower than 1
def euclideanL1(v1: List[Double], v2: List[Double]) = sqrt(v1.zip(v2).map{ case (a, b) =>
    val toPow2 = a - b
    toPow2 * toPow2
  }.sum)    


// Slower than 1
def euclidean5(dot1: Seq[Double], dot2: Seq[Double]): Double =
{
  var sum = 0D
  dot1.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (a, id) =>
    val toPow2 = a - dot2(id)
    sum += toPow2 * toPow2
  }
  sqrt(sum)
}    

// super super slow
def euclidean6(v1: Seq[Double], v2: Seq[Double]) = sqrt(v1.zip(v2).map{ case (a, b) => pow(a - b, 2) }.sum)    


// Slower than 1
def euclidean7(dot1: Seq[Double], dot2: Seq[Double]): Double =
{
  var sum = 0D
  dot1.zip(dot2).foreach{ case (a, b) => sum += pow(a - b, 2) }
  sum
}    

// Slower than 1
def euclidean8(v1: Seq[Double], v2: Seq[Double]) =
{
  def inc(n: Int, v: Double) = {
    val toPow2 = v1(n) - v2(n)
    v + toPow2 * toPow2
  } 

  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(n: Int, v: Double): Double =
  {
    if( n < v1.size - 1 ) go(n + 1, inc(n, v))
    else inc(n, v)
  }

  sqrt(go(0, 0D))
}    

// Slower than 1
def euclideanL2(v1: List[Double], v2: List[Double]) =
{ 
  def inc(vzz: List[(Double, Double)], v: Double): Double =
  {
    val (a, b) = vzz.head
    val toPow2 = a - b
    v + toPow2 * toPow2
  }
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(vzz: List[(Double, Double)], v: Double): Double =
  {
    if( vzz.isEmpty ) v
    else go(vzz.tail, inc(vzz, v))
  }

  sqrt(go(v1.zip(v2), 0D))
}
```

Comment: Questions: What are you benchmarking with (correct answer - JMH)? Have you tried how slow/fast the fully functional approach would be (zipping, multiplying, folding) if you preallocate all functors ahead of time?

Comment: I tested in a simple way by measuring time between two functions on multiple tries with some warmup lunch, but  sqrt(a.zip(b).map(pow2).sum) is way slower

Comment: How long are your vectors?

Comment: Do you do sufficient amount for warmup iterations? With functional syntax it should pass compilation + inlining thresholds which may be quite high for the server JVM.

Comment: I try with 256 its vectors, the fastest of all (but still surprisingly slow) is `sqrt((v1, v2).zipped.map((x, y) => (x-y) * (x-y)).sum)`

Comment: Optimization in JVM is always going to be somewhat subjective because of JIT. So it's hard to make recommendations. That said, using `Seq` adds an element of uncertainty because these collections can be instantiated with different concrete implementations. If you're looking for performance, you should pick a specific implementation. Also, don't call `dot1.size` on every iteration. Call it before starting the loop and use that result.

Comment: It should at the very least be something like `IndexedSeq` and `val n = dot1.size`. Your code has quadratic runtime on `List`s. What do you want with euclidean distance of two vectors anyway...

Comment: With `List` I guess something that doesn't use indices would make more sense - e.g. `zip` and `foldLeft` or tailrec with pattern matching on `(l1, l2) match { case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => ... ; case _ => ... }`.

Comment: E.g. something like https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fFqvc6wQRDeL2uLiYhr81w

Comment: Basically, if you want to have reliable performance you have to have reliable assumptions e.g. you algorithm have to know what data structure is used underneath - Lists shouldn't use indices or appending, Vectors don't work with head-tail destructuring etc. Mean while Seq is just an interface that doesn't give you much guarantees (and quite often defaults to List).

Comment: benchmarking on the JVM is hard. you will not get reliable results just by slinging `System.nanoTime` around. use JMH

Comment: @Kybe - your `euclidean1()` benchmarks with JMH at ~ 260ns on a 3ghz box and 256 elements `Array[Double]`s, with `sqrt()` call removed. This is pretty close to one instruction per tick. Optimizing it further would probably be impractical with a JVM/JIT language.

Comment: @KyBe - for comparison, the one I initially wrote using the functional style syntax `(xs, ys).zipped.map(...)` is ~ 21us per iteration, and thus 100 times slower than `euclidean1()`.

Comment: Though it's quite an old `Core 2 Quad` and JIT does not seem to be vectorizing the loop (`-XX:-UseSuperWord`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried tailrecursion on `List` but not enough efficiently on `ArrayBuffer`, i totally agree with the fact that proper tools like **JMH** are needed to test speed efficiency properly. But when order of magnitude is between 10-50% faster, we can be confident that it is better.

Even if it is `V <: Seq[Double]` it is **NOT** appropriate for `List` but for `ArrayLike` structure.

Here my proposal

```
def euclideanF[V <: Seq[Double]](v1: V, v2: V) = {
   @annotation.tailrec
   def go(d: Double, i: Int): Double = {
     if( i < v1.size ) { 
       val toPow2 = v1(i) - v2(i)
       go(d + toPow2 * toPow2, i + 1)
     }
     else d
   }
   sqrt(go(0D, 0))
}
```